# How do you separate results? Separate a group of rows into separate tables?

Tags: php, sql, html-table

I have what is probably a simple question but can't seem to find a guide or solution.

When you run a query and output the results to a table how do you put the results into separate tables and repeat so it would appear as below.

```
<table>
 <tr><td>title</td><td>date</td>
</tr>
 <tr><td colspan="2">comment</td>
</tr>
Break table and repeat with next result (sperate tables).
 <tr><td>title</td><td>date</td>
</tr>
 <tr><td colspan="2">comment</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I would like it so the whole table is repeated not part of the first results.

```
    $row)
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>"; echo $row['title'] . "</td>";
echo"<td>"; echo $row['date'] . "</td>";
   echo"</tr>";
    echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>"; echo $row['comment'] . "</td>";
   echo"</tr>";
}
```

I made this example to explain a bit better sorry about that.
http://www.thermalzombie.com/temp/example.htm

Comment: What exactly You want? want to display each row result in a separate table ?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what exactly you want,but I guess this may help you

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   ?>
  <table>
  <tr><td><?php echo $row['title'];?></td><td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="2"><?php echo $row['comment'];?></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
<?php
 }
?>
```